# Errno 11001 getaddrinfo failed - Puppeteer and Robotframework

Tags: javascript, python, robotframework, puppeteer

I was trying to explore puppeteer with robotframework, but when I try to run my test it gives me an error.

Error/Warnings:

```
[ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x04AB71C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /chromium-browser-snapshots/Win/588429/chrome-win32.zip
[ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x040A1F40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /chromium-browser-snapshots/Win/588429/chrome-win32.zip
[ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03F17550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /chromium-browser-snapshots/Win/588429/chrome-win32.zip
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: Maximum limit of started keywords exceeded.
Login With Valid Credentials                                          | FAIL |
MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /chromium-browser-snapshots/Win/588429/chrome-win32.zip (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x04AF1358>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Do you have any idea what can I do?
I've searched this issue and some of you said it could be something with urllib3, but I've updated it and still doesn't work.
Thank you

NOTE (CODE)

```
*** Settings ***
Library    PuppeteerLibrary

*** Variables *** 
${SERVER}         example_ip
${ADMINISTRATOR USER}     admin
${VALID PASSWORD}     admin
${URL}      https://${SERVER}
${DEFAULT_BROWSER}    chrome

*** Test Cases ***

Login With Valid Credentials 
    Open Browser To Login Page
    Login Page Should Be Open
    Input Username    ${ADMINISTRATOR USER}
    Input Password    ${VALID PASSWORD}
    Submit Credentials
    Welcome Page Should Be Open

*** Keywords ***
    
Open Browser To Login Page
    Open browser    ${URL}
    Maximize Browser Window

Login Page Should Be Open
    Wait Until Element Is Visible   id:t_login_user    20
    Wait Until Element Is Not Visible    id:loader

Input Username
    [Arguments]    ${username}
    Click Element    id:t_login_user
    Wait Until Element Is Visible   id:t_login_user
    Input Text    css:input.n-input:nth-child(1)   ${username}
    Click Button    name=enter

Input Password
    [Arguments]    ${password}
    Click Element    id:p_login_pwd
    Wait Until Element Is Visible   id:p_login_pwd
    Input Text    css:input.n-input:nth-child(1)   ${password}
    Click Button    name=enter

Submit Credentials
    Click Button    id:login-button

Welcome Page Should Be Open
    Wait Until Element Is Not Visible    id:loader
    Wait Until Page Contains Element   id:Dynamic_1_1
```

Comment: What's your code

Comment: It's a simple example demo - I'll update the questions so you can see @PDHide

Comment: What is your observation till where it is running when is there error thrown

Comment: I start running the robot file and it does not do anything - starts the robot file and then it gives me the errors right away. @PDHide